# Identifying the problems with connect( )

Tags: c, network-programming

I have been working on a proxy server. It has to connect to another "monitor" program and get connection address information from that program. That program in running on a known ip and port. If I use the following to connect it works fine:

```
struct hostent *serv;
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

serv = gethostbyname("localhost");
sockfd = socket(AF)INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd < 0)
      /*   Error handling    */ 
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno); // portno is an int holding the port number
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   /*    error handling   */
```

However I wanted to use the exact ip address instead of local host, they may not alway be on the same machine, and gethostbyname () is obsolete. I attempted to use getaddrinfo() like this:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *server;
int sockfd, i;
char *host = "192.168.2.4";
char *port = "4044";

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;  // have also tried it with 0
i = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &server);
if (i != 0) 
   /*    Error handling   */
sockfd = socket(server->ai_family, server->ai_socktype, server->ai_protocol);
freeaddrinfo (server); // have also tried without this line
if (sockfd < 0)
   /*   Error handling    */
printf("Attempting to connect\n");
if (connect(sockfd, server->ai_addr, server->ai_addrlen) != -1) 
   /*    Error handling   */ 
printf("Connection attempt complete\n");
```

This second attempt hangs for a long time on the connect() command and finally returns in error. I have gone over the examples in several places and searched previous questions here on stackoverflow but can't find the problem, or why one works and the other doesn't. I think it has something to do with the server->ai_addr value but have not been able to verify it yet.

Any help would be appreciated, am I doing something obviously wrong? I don't know where else to look for more ideas to check.

EDIT UPDATE: 
I have figured out one problem. In the line if (connect (/*    */) != -1) 
it should have been != 0. One of the samples I was looking at used a bind() statement instead. If I use the local host address with the second may it will work with that change. However I still can't connect to a specific ip address node. I am beginning to suspect that the ip address I was given isn't one that this computer can receive network traffic on. I am not sure how to check that though. I will see If I can figure out any more info on the error with using the specific ip address and edit again with the information.

EDIT UPDATE: I added #include  and tried to print out the error code after the system call returns. I also printed out the return. It returns a -1 which according to the documentation I found just means an error occurred when I try to print out the errno it seg faults.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error Code %s\n", errno); // seg faults
```

However changing it to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error Code %d\n", errno); // returns Error Code 60
```

Comment: Just wondering, are you closing the previous connection anywhere? Is your monitor Program ready to accept multiple connections?

Comment: The monitor program so far is just an echo server that reports it has a connection, what it received and echos it back. I can use use multiple copies of clients logging into all at the same time, including this one if I use the first code with gethostbyname(). I also have the same error even if it is the only one logging into the monitor.

Comment: As an aside, you can zero `hints` automatically w/out the memset call like this: `struct addrinfo hints = {};`  The standard says to initialize corresponding elements (when brace initializing) with values provided; elements not initialized (eg, if you only add 1 value to the brace list) are automatically zeroed.  Furthermore, you can leave it empty which will zero initialize the entire struct or array.

Comment: hints can be null.  constants that can be used for `ai_flags` include `AI_PASSIVE, AI_CANONNAME, AI_NUMERICHOST, AI_V4MAPPED, AI_ALL, AI_ADDRCONFIG, AI_IDN, AI_CANONIDN, AI_IDN_ALLOW_UNASSIGNED, AI_IDN_USE_STD3_ASCII_RULES, AI_NUMERIC_SERV`.  If you want info on them, open the `netdb.h` header (in linux anyway) and there's a comment adjacent to each one.

Comment: You said "finally returns in error" but you did not say which one.

Comment: 'Returns in error' is not an adequate problem description. What's the errno? perror()?

Comment: So having figured out that errno is an int, not a pointer to a string, *what did it print?*

Comment: The errno that prints is 60, I haven't found out what 60 is yet though. I have found some stuff on linux systems, I am on a max OS X, and if they are the same it would mean time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ip address that I was given is not the ip on the computer I am using. I finally decided that the ip address had to be the problem. I found the ip address on my computer and got the server program to bind to it. I also put it in as the ip address for the code included above instead of local host and it was able to connect regardless of rather the server was on that specific ip address or simply connected to INADDR_ANY.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
hints.ai_flags = 0;
```

with

```
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, tried that with the same results. So do you know where I can find a complete list of the flags and their meaning?

Comment: @EdwardGoodson At least under linux, it should be as easy as `man getaddrinfo` and read the docs.